# fetch_assoc only 10 result instead of all

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $top = db::find_by('pl_id', 'playlist', '1', 'order by sort ASC');

$c = 0;
$ids = '';

while ($row = $top->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($c <10) {
        $aid = $row['aid'];
        $oid = $row['oid'];
        $ids .= $aid . '_' . $oid . ',';
        $c++;
    }
}
```

I only get one result, but it should be a lot more. How do I get all the results?

Comment: remove the check for $c<10 ..

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are limiting the echo for only 10 result

remove the check for $c<10

```
    while ($row = $top->fetch_assoc()) {

          $aid = $row['aid'];
          $oid = $row['oid'];
          $ids .= $aid . '_' . $oid . ',';

  }
```

Comment: check better  .. are you sure your  $top return a valid result  .. try var_dump($row) . fore check the content .. and let me know ... is not possible that with the if you have one result and without you have 0  .. no sense

Comment: string(9) "456413764" ["sort"]=> string(1) "5" ["pl_id"]=> string(1) "1" } array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "35" ["aid"]=> string(9) "253651296" ["oid"]=> string(9) "456240447" ["sort"]=> string(1) "6" ["pl_id"]=> string(1) "1" } array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "34" ["aid"]=> string(9) "371745462" ["oid"]=> string(9) "456486075" ["sort"]=> string(1) "7" ["pl_id"]=> string(1) "1" } array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "33" ["aid"]=> string(9) "371745465" ["oid"]=> string(9) "456401112" ["sort"]=> string(1) "8" ["pl_id"]=> string(1) "1" } array(5) { ["id"]=> string(2) "31" ["aid"]=> string(9) "371745443"